# two dimensional char array in C

Tags: c

On the code below,

```
char strArr[5][20];
int i;

for(i=0; i<5; i++)  
{  
   printf("string %d: ", i+1);  
   gets(strArr[i]);  
}

strArr[0]=strArr[1]; //have an compile error on this line. Why cannot assign?
```

As commented on the last line of code block above, why has a compile error (incompatible type)? Both left and right operands are char* type?

Comment: Use fgets() instead gets() to avoid buffer overflow. fgets(strArr[i], 20, stdin).

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with 2D arrays. It is just about arrays as such.

Answer (score 4):

Both the left and right operands are of the type `char[20]`, not `char*`. The variables actually have storage reserved for them, they aren't simply pointers to strings. So the assignment, if it were legal, would be copying 20 characters from one array to the other.

C doesn't let you copy arrays with an assignment operator. Use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, or `memcpy` instead.

(I suspect the specific wording of the error is because an array decays into a pointer in some places, and I expect the left side of an assignment is *not* one of those places, while being used on the right side of an assignment is.)

Comment: `strcpy` will only work if the array contains a null-terminated string

Answer (score 2):

`char Array[n][m]` : In almost all language, it means : array of array. So, `Array[0]` `Array[1]`.... is an array. In fact, it is a pointer point to continuous memory of each elements.

And type of this array is  : `char[m]`. And, when you write : `arrayX = arrayY`, you want copy all values in arrayY to arrayX, but C doesn't allow this. You must copy by hand :

```
for(int i=0; i<=sizeof(arrayX)/sizeof(char); i++)
      arrayX[i] = arrayY[i];
```

I often use  `memcpy`, but the background is base on the code above.

```
 memcpy (strArray[1],strArray[0],sizeof(strArr[0]));
```

But, if you declare like this, no compile-error :

`char * strArray[5][10]`;

because, it just copy value of pointer : mean copy where this pointer point to. But of course, It changes your code very much. I just draw here for more clearer.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the base address of the char array strArray[0] with that of strArray[1], which is not permitted.
Hence you are getting the error.

Comment: char* str1="CPointer"; char* str2="C++Pointer"; str1=str2; no compile error for this. I think you can change the base address. Compiler says this issue is caused by incompatible type.